# OpenGL - Get color of a pixel

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, computer-science, pyopengl

I am trying to implement **Boundary Fill Algorithm** in **OpenGL** using **python**, and facing trouble with obtaining the color of the pixel in consideration.

Tried to use this function:
`glReadPixels(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, void * data)`

but can't exactly figure out how it works even after reading the documentation.

Even if I use this function, what values does it return as 'data'. Is it the RGBA values or the HEX code?
Which data structure can I use to store it because I am unfamiliar with 'struct' in Python. Can I use a list?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) to convert the string to a byte array:

```py
import numpy
```

```py
data = glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
byte_array = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype='uint8')
print(list(byte_array))
```

Or use [`ctypes.from_buffer_copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer_copy)

```py
import ctypes
```

```py
data = glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
byte_array = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 4).from_buffer_copy(data)
print(list(byte_array))
```